# Migrating From 9.0 to 10.3 one instance to other

Tags: sitecore-client, migration

I need to migrate the site in Sitecore version 9.0 to 10.3 from one instance to another
The current site is using layered architecture however we need it in helix.
I need to migrate below data :

- Sitecore Content (One instance to another and convert to helix format)
- Analytics Data
- EXM Data
- Sitecore Users

What should be the best and easiest way for this migration?

Comment: This question is really a very large discussion point, there are so many variables that its not a great fit for SSE. The "best way to do x" - will often depend very much on what you have in place, what your existing 9.0 site looks like etc... and much of it will be opinion based. For example - Helix... that can be very polarizing.  You would be better to take this to the community forums or [Sitecore Slack](https://sitecore.chat) to have a conversation about it.

Answer (score 0):

The benefits that Sitecore Helix provides to a Sitecore implementation, such as future-proof architecture that is easy to maintain and extend. The plan for migration is to transfer the group logic from your old projects into Helix-based modules. All you need is a reference web project when detaching pieces of code and grouping them into separate modules.

Here's a general outline of the steps you might take to migrate a site from a traditional Sitecore architecture to Helix:

1. Familiarize yourself and your team with the principles of the Helix architecture. Follow the [helix architecture](https://helix.sitecore.com/) document.
2. Analyze your existing Sitecore solution to identify logical modules/components. Evaluate the current architecture and how it maps to Helix principles. Plan the target architecture within the Helix framework. Define modules, layers, and dependencies.
3. Set up a new Helix solution using Helix Visual Studio templates or manually configure the structure. Define projects for each module according to the Helix guidelines (Foundation, Feature, Project layers).
4. Identify logical components/modules in your existing Sitecore solution.
   Separate these modules into individual projects within your Helix solution.
5. Refactor code to fit the Helix structure. This might involve breaking down monolithic components into smaller, modular pieces.
6. Adjust configuration files to reflect the new structure.
   Update dependencies between modules.
7. Conduct thorough testing to ensure that the migration hasn't introduced regressions. Review the architecture to ensure it aligns with Helix principles.

After you migrate, your solution will look like the following architecture.

[image]

Along with this, there are a few reference documents you can follow to see how they migrated their project into helix helix-based solution.

https://www.sam-solutions.com/blog/migrating-to-helix/

https://pratiksatikunvar.wordpress.com/2017/07/02/sitecore-helix-converting-existing-sitecore-solution-into-helix-standards/

https://www.mtelligent.com/home/2017/10/13/best-practices-for-sitecore-helix-and-general-development

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there any utility available to transfer sitecore content, analytics data,exm data and sitecore users from one instance to other.

Comment: @Aditya Well I didn't find such utility but here is a basic helix solution that you can use https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples

Comment: Please don't use Helix...

Answer (score 0):

There's no utility that would convert a non-Helix project to a Helix one (at least I'm aware not aware of it).
You could follow either of the 2 approaches:

1. Convert the solution in 9.0 to Helix compatible and then follow the upgrade guide from Sitecore to upgrade it to 10.3 or
2. Upgrade the current instance to 10.3 and then make it Helix compatible.

I would suggest to go for option 1. That way you can get rid of stuff which is not needed making your upgrade a little easier.

For the Analytics and EXM Data, you need to execute the database upgrade scripts and rebuild the reporting database. If everything goes as per the upgrade guide then you should see both data in your new 10.3 instance